# Build a array of div's id using each DIV inside section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the ID of each DIV inside this HTML code

```
<section id="choices">    
    <div id="talla_choice_24" style="">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="color_choice_25" style="">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="sport_choice_26" style="">
        ...
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="create-variation" id="create-variation" style="">Crear variaciones</button>
    <section id="variations_holder" style="display: none"></section>
</section>
```

So I made this:

```
function getDivId(div) {
    var inputValues = [];
    $("#" + div + ' > div').each(function() {
        inputValues.push($(this).val());
    })
    return inputValues;
}
```

And I call here:

```
$('#choices').on("click", "#create-variation", function(e) {
    var parent_id = $(this).closest("section").attr("id");
    var element = getDivId(parent_id);

    iterateChoices("", element[0], element.slice(1), 0);
});
```

I need to build something like this:

```
var element = new Array($('#talla_choice_24 input:text'), $('#color_choice_25 input:text'), $('#sport_choice_26 input:text'));
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'each'

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is the code for `iterateChoices()` function:

```
function iterateChoices(row, element, choices, counter) {
    if ($.isArray(choices) && choices.length > 0) {
        element.each(function(index, item) {
            if (counter == 0)
                row = '<input type="text" required="required" value="" name="pupc[]" /><input type="text" required="required" value="" name="pprice[]" /><input type="text" required="required" value="" name="pqty[]" />';

            iterateChoices(row + '<input value="' + item.value + '">', choices[0], choices.slice(1), counter + 1);
        });
    } else {
        html_temp = "";
        $.each(element, function(index, item) {
            html_temp += row + '<input value="' + item.value + '"><br>';
        });
        html += html_temp;
    }
}
```

I also made some changes at this code:

```
function getDivId(div) {
    var inputValues = [];
    $("#" + div + ' > div').each(function() {
        inputValues.push("#" + $(this).attr('id') + ' input:text');
    });

    return inputValues;
}
```

And now the error change to this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #talla_choice_24 input:text has no method 'each'

**UPDATE 2**

I still continue change `getDivId()` function to build a array like this:

```
 var element = new Array($('#talla_choice_24 input:text'), $('#color_choice_25 input:text'), $('#number_choice_23 input:text'), $('#sport_choice_23 input:text'));
```

But can't get it since array values are constructed as strings, see below:

```
function getDivId(div) {
    var inputValues = [];
    $("#" + div + ' > div').each(function() {

        inputValues.push('$("#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' input:text")');
    });

    return inputValues;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
("$('#talla_choice_24 input:text')", "$('#color_choice_25 input:text')")
```

I think there is the problem

Comment: can you show your iterateChoices() function ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 added to the main post and some other changes

Comment: you're calling .each() on element within iterateChoices(), but with the parameters you're passing in, element isn't a jquery object.

Comment: @BYossarian yes, that's the problem but I can't find how to fix it :-(

Comment: well, for starters, even if getDivId() were returning a jquery object (which it isn't at the moment), then using element[0] returns the DOMObject within the jquery object at position 0. I think you want this: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @BYossarian how `eq` will help me here? I'm passing the first value of `element` array

Comment: ah, ok - i was thinking you wanted element to be a jquery object. my bad...

Comment: ok, so im still a bit confused about what you want overall, but i think you just need to edit getDivId() so the line reads: inputValues.push($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:text"));  Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some headaches I realized how to fix the (my) error, here is the solution to all the problems:

```
function getDivId(div) {
    var inputValues = [];
    $("#" + div + ' > div').each(function() {
        inputValues.push($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " input:text"));
    });

    return inputValues;
}
```

Comment: I think the answer I gave is a little more succinct :) - But glad you sorted it.

Comment: You don't need to get the id, just use the element directly intead of building a selector that finds it again: `inputValues.push($("input:text", this));`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `val` method on a `div` element, which just returns an empty string. There is no `each` method on a string.

---

You don't need the id of each div to get the input elements inside them. This will get you the inputs in a single jQuery object:

```
var element = $(this).closest("section").find("> div input:text");
```

If you really need an array of separate jQuery objects, you can then do this:

```
element = element.map(function(){ return $(this); }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
$("#create-variation").on('click', function(){
    $("#choices > div").each(function(a,b){
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).attr('id')` instead of the `$(this).text()`?

Comment: Yeh if thats what he wants - we should just be pointing in the right direction. Teach a man to fish and all that :)